# Lectura de cadenas en C

Tags: c

tengo una duda con respecto a la lectura de cadenas en C. Escribí este código y me corrigieron la parte en donde se lee el string texto. anteriormente tenía escrito esto:

```
scanf("%10000[^\n]\n",texto);
```

y creo que no entendí realmente la entrada de cadenas en C. Si alguien me pudiera explicar en que radica la diferencia de las siguientes dos entradas:

`scanf("%10000[^\n]\n",texto);` y  `scanf("%10000[^\n]s", texto); getchar();`

y también cual es el objetivo del uso de `getchar()`. Si alguien pudiera responder estas dudas se lo agradecería mucho. Saludos

```
#include  <stdio.h>
#include  <string.h>
#include  <stdlib.h>
int main(void)
{
    char texto[10001];
    char cadena[101];

    // ENTRADAS.

    scanf("%10000[^\n]s", texto);
    getchar();

    scanf("%100[^\n]s",cadena);

    //-----------------------Proceso-------------------------

    char *puntero = texto;

    unsigned short longitud = strlen(cadena);

    char auxiliar[10001];

    while ( (puntero = strstr(texto,cadena)) != NULL)
    {
        strcpy(auxiliar,"\0");
        strncat(auxiliar, texto, puntero - texto);
        puntero = puntero + longitud;
        strcat(auxiliar,puntero);
        strcpy(texto, "\0");
        strcpy(texto,auxiliar);
    }

    printf("%s",texto);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

A `scanf()` tienes que pasarle como primer argumento una cadena de formato que indique el tipo de datos que tiene que leer. En tu caso lees una cadena, por lo que la cadena de formato sería (en principio) `"%s"`. Es la `s` la que indica **s**tring.

Sin embargo `"%s"` plantea dos problemas:

1. Leerá caracteres hasta encontrarse con el primer espacio en blanco y ahí se detendrá (dejando el resto de caracteres que hubiera tecleado el usuario sin leer, a la espera del siguiente `scanf()`). Esto no es normalmente lo que quieres, ya que sólo permitiría leer una palabra si el usuario había escrito varias separadas por espacios.
2. Es posible que el usuario escriba más caracteres de los que podemos guardar en la variable `texto`. `scanf()` no comprueba los límites de esa variable (en realidad no puede hacerlo aunque quisiera, porque todo lo que recibe es la dirección donde comienza el array `texto`, pero no su tamaño). Si el usuario escribiera más caracteres (sin espacios) de los que caben, el resto sobreescribirían otras partes de la memoria del programa, con el riesgo de seguridad que ello conlleva (ataques por *buffer overrun*).

Por ambas razones no suele usarse `scanf()` para leer líneas de texto, sino `fgets(texto, tamano_maximo, stdin)`.

En cambio en tu ejercicio, has optado por una solución que, si te soy franco, nunca había visto y nunca se me habría ocurrido, y es usar como cadena de formato `"%10000[^\n]s"`. Esta cadena de formato sigue esperando un **s**tring, por la `s` del final, pero todo lo anterior da indicaciones a `scanf()` de qué esperar. El número (`10000`) sería el máximo de caracteres a leer. Eso evita el posible *buffer overrun*. El `[^\n]` indica la categoría de caracteres a admitir, y es una especie de expresión regular que significa "todo lo que no sea el carácter `\n`".

Por tanto esa cadena de formato leería una línea completa, con espacios y todo, deteniéndose en cuanto encuentre un `\n`, o cuando haya leido 10000 caracteres (lo que ocurra antes).

Cuando el usuario escriba algo, por ejemplo "Hola", y pulse retorno de carro, en el buffer de entrada estará la secuencia de caracteres `"Hola\n"`, ya que el retorno de carro introducido por el usuario se codifica como `\n`.

Entonces `scanf()` leerá todos los caracteres hasta el `\n` (en este caso cuatro) y los dejará en el array `texto`. El `\n` queda sin leer, a la espera de la próxima instrucción que lea algo de la entrada estándar. Es por ese `\n` que se hace luegom un `getchar()`, para "consumirlo", pues de lo contrario sería encontrado por el próximo `scanf()` que hicieras, lo que le confundiría y consideraría que la entrada es una línea en blanco.

Como dije antes, este lío podría simplificarse mucho si usaras:

```
fgets(texto, 10000, stdin);
```

pues `fgets()` admite cualquier secuencia de letras (incluyendo espacios), tiene un parámetro para especificarle el máximo a leer, y además *consume* el `\n` final evitando la necesidad del `getchar()`. El `\n` leído iría a parar a la variable `texto`, podrías eliminarlo con un `texto[strlen(texto)]=0;` si no lo quisieras.

Por cierto que tu `scanf("%10000[^\n]\n",texto);` no es correcto porque la cadena de formato no especifica el tipo de datos a leer.

Comment: Muchas gracias hermano, ahora entendí mejor....Saludos

Comment: Recuerda visitar el [tour] para ver como marcar las preguntas como aceptadas.