# Programa no realiza el recorrido correspondiente en una funcion

Tags: c

No se por qué motivo o razón no realiza el recorrido correspondiente en la función *procesarDatosPasajeros()* y simplemente pasa a la función que termina el programa, sin antes realizar el recorrido por el while en donde al final de este, se vuelve a la primer función del programa para permitir ingresar o no datos al usuario.

Código de la función:

```
void procesarDatosPasajeros() {
    
    while (cargarDatos == 1) {
        procesarMenoresEdad();
        calcularVuelosInternacionales();
        calcularVuelosTotales();
        calcularPorcentajeVuelosInternacionales();
        ingresarDatosPasajeros();
    }
}
```

Copio mi código completo:

```
#include <stdio.h>

/* 3)   Aerolíneas Argentinas cuenta con los siguientes datos de sus pasajeros: Apellido y Nombre, Destino (1-Nacional, 2-Internacional), 
menor de edad (S/N). Desea obtener un listado de los pasajeros menores de edad. También desea conocer la cantidad de pasajeros que realizarán un viaje internacional, 
y el porcentaje que representan en el total de pasajeros.
El proceso finaliza cuando el usuario no tiene más pasajeros para procesar.
*/

/* Variables */
char apellidoYnombre;
int destino;
char menorEdad;
int cargarDatos;
float porcentajeVuelosInternacionales;

/* Variables contadores */
int cantVuelosInternacionales = 0;
int cantVuelosTotales = 0;

/* Estrategia */
void ingresarDatosPasajeros();
void procesarDatosPasajeros();
void mostrarResultadosObtenidos();

/* Otras funciones */
void procesarMenoresEdad();
void calcularVuelosInternacionales();
void calcularVuelosTotales();
void calcularPorcentajeVuelosInternacionales();

int main() {
    ingresarDatosPasajeros();
    procesarDatosPasajeros();
    mostrarResultadosObtenidos();
    return 0;
}

void ingresarDatosPasajeros() {
    
    printf("Desea cargar datos de un pasajero? '1' SI // '2' NO \n");
    fflush(stdin);
    scanf("%d", &cargarDatos);
    if(cargarDatos == 1) {
        
        printf("Ingrese Apellido y Nombre: \n");
        fflush(stdin);
        scanf("%s[^\n]", &apellidoYnombre);
        
        fflush(stdin);
        printf("Es menor de edad? 'S' // 'N' \n");
        scanf("%c", &menorEdad);
        
        fflush(stdin);
        printf("Ingrese su destino: '1' Nacional // '2' Internacional \n");
        scanf("%d", &destino);
    }
}

void procesarDatosPasajeros() {
    
    while (cargarDatos == 1) {
        procesarMenoresEdad();
        calcularVuelosInternacionales();
        calcularVuelosTotales();
        calcularPorcentajeVuelosInternacionales();
        ingresarDatosPasajeros();
    }
}

void procesarMenoresEdad() {
    
    if(menorEdad == 's' || menorEdad == 'S') {
        printf("Apellido y nombre: %s", apellidoYnombre);
        printf("Destino: %d", destino);
        printf("Menor de edad: SI");
    }
}

void calcularVuelosInternacionales() {
    if(destino == 2) {
        cantVuelosInternacionales = cantVuelosInternacionales + 1;
    }
}

void calcularVuelosTotales() {
    if(destino == 1 || destino == 2) {
        cantVuelosTotales = cantVuelosTotales + 1;
    }
}

void calcularPorcentajeVuelosInternacionales() {
    
    porcentajeVuelosInternacionales = (float) (cantVuelosInternacionales / cantVuelosTotales) * 100;
}

void mostrarResultadosObtenidos() {
    
    printf("\nLa cantidad de personas que realizaran un vuelo internacional es de: %d \n", cantVuelosInternacionales);
    printf("Estos representan el %.2f %% sobre la cantidad total de vuelos.\n", porcentajeVuelosInternacionales);
}
```

Comment: ¿No puedes depurar paso por paso para ver qué sucede?

Comment: Podría ser un problema de lectura de cadenas debido a `scanf()` y a espacios o retornos de carro pendientes en `stdin`. Puedes ver problemas similares [aqui](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/201583/7123) por si se trata de eso. Por cierto que `fflush(stdin)` no hace nada y no tiene sentido.

Comment: @PaperBirdMaster lo que sucede es que luego de ingresar los datos, el programa simplemente se "saltea" la funcion procesarDatosPasajeros() y pasa a la función final que es mostrarResultadosObtenidos(), podría agregar fotos y demás para ilustrar mejor el post, pero para ello he copiado el código completo por si acaso quieres probarlo y ver por ti mismo, se me hace raro y la verdad es que no se que estoy haciendo mal.

Comment: @TysonelPitbull qué casualidad que la única función que se "saltea" sea la única que tiene una condición para ejecutarse... apuesto a que depurando paso por paso podríamos ver que la condición no se cumple.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El error lo encontre al declarar la siguiente variable:
char apellidoYnombre; porque no especifique cuantos caracteres máximo puede contener entonces, al ingresar mas de un carácter hace que el programa trunque, lo solucione agregando un máximo de por ejemplo, 30 caracteres.
char apellidoYnombre[30];